# Wait notify pthreads unix C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, pthreads

I have n threads , each modifying an object O(k) where k can be 0 to n-1.

Now there is a listener thread l, that needs to get an alert when any of the thread,k, has modified its object O(k)

What is the fastest way to implement this situation ?

Comment: You can use a *condition variable* - google for details/examples....

Comment: @Ram Any success using my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Posix (or even better, std C++) condition variable, as one commentor already suggested. You can use the related mutex to protect a std::array of flags, one flag per worker thread. When a worker thread modifies its object, it acquires mutex and raises its flag. When the listener thread is notified, it will service the k:th object (corresponding to k:th flag in array) and lower the flag, then release mutex.

Be sure to read examples for condvars so you understand when mutex is automatically acquired/released.

In general, std C++ threading primitives are easier to use, since they use e.g. RAII for automatic unlocking of mutexes etc. Also portable to non-Posix environments. But here is a pthreads example from

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_var   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *functionCount1();
void *functionCount2();
int  count = 0;
#define COUNT_DONE  10
#define COUNT_HALT1  3
#define COUNT_HALT2  6

main()
{
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;

   pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionCount1, NULL);
   pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionCount2, NULL);

   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

   printf("Final count: %d\n",count);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

// Write numbers 1-3 and 8-10 as permitted by functionCount2()

void *functionCount1()
{
   for(;;)
   {
      // Lock mutex and then wait for signal to relase mutex
      pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );

      // Wait while functionCount2() operates on count
      // mutex unlocked if condition varialbe in functionCount2() signaled.
      pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var, &count_mutex );
      count++;
      printf("Counter value functionCount1: %d\n",count);

      pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

      if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);
    }
}

// Write numbers 4-7

void *functionCount2()
{
    for(;;)
    {
       pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );

       if( count < COUNT_HALT1 || count > COUNT_HALT2 )
       {
          // Condition of if statement has been met. 
          // Signal to free waiting thread by freeing the mutex.
          // Note: functionCount1() is now permitted to modify "count".
          pthread_cond_signal( &condition_var );
       }
       else
       {
          count++;
          printf("Counter value functionCount2: %d\n",count);
       }

       pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

       if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);
    }

}
```